# Populating a dropdownlist using a SQL Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I have a DropdownList in asp.net form that needs populating through SQL. I'm using a `ScriptManager` in my `Page_Load()`and due to this dropdownList doesn't get populated. I need to use the `ScriptManager` since I'm using a `AjaxCalendarExtender`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataSet ds = dba.getNames();
        ddNames.DataSource = ds.Tables["EMPLOYEE"].DefaultView;
        ddNames.DataTextField = "Username";
        ddNames.DataValueField = "Username";
        ddNames.DataBind(); 
    }  
    if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page) == null)
    {
        Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, new ScriptManager());
    }
}
```

getNames() function in DB_Access.cs

```
public DataSet getNames()
{
    if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    newCmd.Connection = conn;
    newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    newCmd.CommandText = "Select DISTINCT Username from dbo.EMPLOYEE";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(newCmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "EMPLOYEE");

    conn.Close();

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: intresting. where is questione

Comment: code doesn't return the values to the Drop Down List. Shows an empty drop down list. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be in the Script Manager in `aspx` page instead of Creating the it Dynamically in the Page Load event.

> `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />`